# Plugging a "last row" variable into a workday function/formula

Tags: vba

I have a set of daily time series data spanning thousands of rows with their corresponding variables  over several columns. I'd like to create a legend of the set's beginning and ending dates, rounded to the closest work date. I'm using the workday() function but can't seem to properly reference the last row...

```
 Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 15).FormulaR1C1 = "=workday((r&Lastrow)c[-14],-1)"
```

I'm returning a 1004 runtime error with this piece of code, anybody care to explain where the error is?

Comment: The formula itself contains an error. Simply entering '=workday((r&Endvalue)c[-14],-1)' into a cell gives me the same error, so the problem is the formula, not the VBA code. Also, I notice the formula does not reference your `Lastrow` variable. Is this intentional? Please provide more context.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the "Lastrow" variable reference has been rectified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lastrow` is a VBA variable, so you cannot reference it in a formula - the worksheet doesn't know what that variable is. Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
"=workday(r[" & Lastrow & "]c[-14],-1)"
```

Also, remove the extra parenthesis and make sure you check the "R1C1 Reference Style" option for this to work.